# Error in Updating RecyclerView in a Dialog

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

The idea of my project is to click in one recyclerView in MainActivity and after one dialog with other recyclerView is opened. 
The error is that my recyclerView isn't updating in the Dialog

**MainActivity:**

```
private fun openDialog(postModel: PostModel){
    CommentDialogFragment(postModel).show(supportFragmentManager, "dialog")
}
```

**CommentDialogFragment:**

```
class CommentDialogFragment(postSelected: PostModel): AppCompatDialogFragment() {
private var mCommentsList: MutableList<CommentModel> = arrayListOf()
private val mCommentServiceRequest = CommentServiceRequest()
private lateinit var mContext: Context
private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
private var postModel: PostModel = postSelected
private lateinit var mCommentListAdapter: CommentListAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)
}

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val viewGroup = inflater.inflate(R.layout.comment, container)
    mContext = inflater.context
    mCommentListAdapter = CommentListAdapter(mCommentsList)
    mRecyclerView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewComments)
    setupCommentObserver(postModel.id)
    loadCommentRecyclerView()
    dialog!!.setTitle("${mContext.getString(R.string.comments)} ${postModel.title}")
    return viewGroup
}

private fun setupCommentObserver(postId: Int){
    mCommentServiceRequest.searchCommentsFromAPI(postId)
        .observe(this, Observer { comments ->
            if (comments != null){
                mCommentsList = comments.toMutableList()
                mCommentListAdapter.setData(mCommentsList)
            }
        })
}

private fun loadCommentRecyclerView() {
    mCommentsList.clear()
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    mRecyclerView.adapter = mCommentListAdapter
    mRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(mContext)
}}
```

**CommentListAdapter:**

```
class CommentListAdapter(private var commentList: MutableList<CommentModel>):
                  RecyclerView.Adapter<CommentViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CommentViewHolder {
    val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.comment_list , parent, false)
    return CommentViewHolder(view)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return commentList.count()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CommentViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindTask(commentList[position])
}

fun setData(list: MutableList<CommentModel>){
    this.commentList = list
    this.notifyDataSetChanged()
}}
```

I did the same thing in other project without use notifyDataSetChanged() only using callbacks and worked, so I tried here too but didn't work, I think the dialog is the problem

Comment: What exactly is the problem here? Please update the title and post with the problem you are facing.

Comment: this.commentList.clear()
        this.commentList.addAll(list)
        this.notifyDataSetChanged()    can you try this

Comment: I tried this before but it does not work and it's strange because my CommentDialogFragment get a new instance always the openDialog() is called however the recycler is not reloaded

Comment: Are you sure call setData. Second question  which line call first => mRecyclerView.adapter = mCommentListAdapter or mCommentListAdapter.setData(mCommentsList)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, mRecyclerView.adapter = mCommentListAdapter is executed first because mCommentListAdapter.setData(mCommentsList) is inside a observer